# Julia: Call previous value within Map function

Tags: julia, higher-order-functions

I have been acclimating myself with the higher order functions like map, filter, and reduce. Honestly, I feel like I'm cheating because the code is so clean! Anyway...

Say I am preforming a map function on an array and the output of anonymous function is dependent on the preceding value. How would i call the previous value?

For instance:

A statement to check if each value has a factor of 3

```
julia> A
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  6
  9
 36

julia> reduce(&, map(x-> x%3 == 0, A))
true
```

How would I call the previous value to check if it is a factor of the current value?

```
julia> reduce(&, map( x -> x==A[1] ? true : x % 3 == 0, A))
true

#I want to change the 3 to the previous value like..
psuedo code> reduce(&, map( x -> x==A[1] ? true : x % x[i-1] == 0, A))
```

Any ideas? Or, am I pushing the limits on this?

Comment: `reduce(&, map(x-> x%3 == 0, A))` is really slow and verbose. You should rather use `mapreduce(x-> x%3 == 0, &, A)`, or, even better, `all(x-> x%3 == 0, A)`.

Comment: does the mapreduce function work with multivariate function? Can't seem to get it to work with the following:
```julia
mapreduce( (x,y) -> x-y > 0 ? true  : false,+ ,A[2:end], A[1:end-1])
```

Comment: It doesn't take that many arguments, so you zip them into one: `mapreduce(x -> x[1]-x[2] > 0, +, zip(A[2:end], A[1:end-1]))`. BTW, your anonymous function was needlessly complicated. Alternatively, just write `count(x -> x[1]-x[2] > 0, zip(A[2:end], A[1:end-1]))`.

Comment: BTW, in version 1.2 `mapreduce` will accept multiple input arguments, just like `map`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function can take a multivariate function and apply it to multiple arrays. So you can apply your function to properly shifted versions of your array:

```
julia> A = [3, 6, 9, 36];

julia> map((x, y) -> x % y == 0, A[2:end], A[1:end-1])
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
  true
```

The [ShiftedArrays.jl](https://github.com/piever/ShiftedArrays.jl) package provides `lead` and `lag` functions to make shifting arrays more convenient:

```
julia> using ShiftedArrays

julia> lag(A)
4-element ShiftedArray{Int64,Missing,1,Array{Int64,1}}:
  missing
 3       
 6       
 9

julia> map((x, x_lag) -> x % x_lag == 0, A, lag(A))
4-element Array{Union{Missing, Bool},1}:
      missing
  true       
 false       
  true
```

Note that `lag` introduces a `missing` value at the beginning of the shifted array. If you want to ensure that your function returns `true` for the first element of the array, you could modify it like this:

```
julia> map((x, y) -> ismissing(y) ? true : x % y == 0, A, lag(A))
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
  true
 false
  true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as in a for loop, you can take elements as x in A or get elements via an index, as i in 1:length(A):

```
reduce(&, map(i -> A[i]==A[1] ? true : A[i] % A[i-1] == 0, 1:length(A)))
```

or, because it may shortcut evaluation when false:

```
all(i -> A[i]==A[1] ? true : A[i] % A[i-1] == 0, 1:length(A))
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think I could use a range.

Thanks for the insight!